# How to autoclick my image slider's 'next' arrow?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

A website I am working on is using Semplice theme in Wordpress. They have a built-in slider that does not autoplay. My workaround was to try to have jquery autoclick the 'next' arrow on the slider every 5 seconds but have it stop when I click another link on the page cause I found that it would not let me load another page since it kept autoclicking 'next'. I tried the code below and it would autoclick to the next slide but stopped after.

Here is the code I am trying out (custom jquery needs to be wrapped in semplice's functions)

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            $("a.next").trigger('click');
        }, 5000);
    });
    $(':not(a.next)').on('click', function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have you confirmed that there is no feature to autoplay with their support staff? -- http://help.semplicelabs.com/  -- it seems to autoplay just fine here -- http://www.semplicelabs.com/

Comment: Yeah, I have verified with their staff that autoplay is not built in their slider. They said I would need custom js/css to do it and I have been researching ever since. You can see the slider in action on one of their showcase sites. http://www.pleksi.de/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$("a.next").trigger('click');` try `$("a.next").click();`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("a.next").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
      });
      interval = window.setInterval(function () {
          $("a.next").click();
      }, 5000);
});
```

Unless you have a prevent default, anchors will try to reload or send you to a new page, since I don't know what the other plugin is doing I can't tel if this will work, you should read the documentation of the plugin to see how to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I tried that and it autoclicks once and then just stops

Comment: I wanted to do something similar once and I remember this doesn't work in Safari.

Comment: I gues the problem is that its an anchor, by default an anchor will send you  to another place. try to add a prevent default, I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks! I tried that update and it clicks through all slides, however, when I click a nav link to go to another page, it becomes blank, but you can see the autoclick still going because the url of each slide change every couple seconds

Comment: No unfortunately without looking at it is very difficult to find a solution, specially as I said before because we don't know how the plugin works, did you look into the documentation of the plugin?

Comment: Yeah I did but nothing. Anyways, thanks for all your help!